# Comparação de Horários em aproximação

Tags: php

Como posso fazer um script para se hora atual estiver chegando a hora marcada fazer alguma coisa

```
  Exemplo

  date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
  $hora_atual = date('H:i'); //11:45 Hora Atual      
  $hora_marcada              // 12:00 hora marcada vem do banco 

  se horario atual estiver faltando <= 15 minutos para a hora marcada{

  exemp .echo falta 15 minutos para saida  
  }
```

Comment: Da uma olhada na classe DateTime do `php`

Comment: Depende de todo o resto do código que vc não colocou na pergunta. Em que variáveis está esse tempo, onde está o script, como vai ser executado, etc. - Normalmente é só um pequeno IF com uma conversão em minutos ou segundos, depende como armazena a data.

Comment: Ou pode-se usar o `time()` mesmo, ele retorna o timestamp atual, dai voce armazena em uma variável e inicio e acrescenta mais 15 minutos (com `tempo + (15*60)`) e armazena na variável saida, apos isso é so pegar a saida - a entrada e multiplicar por 60 para ter o numero de minutos restantes.

Comment: Funções time e date no PHP dão de mil a zero naquela porcaria de DateTime tanto em performance quanto simplicidade :)

Comment: Concordo kk a vantagem o `DateTime` é que faz alguns cálculos automáticos, como dias de semana, etc. Mas pra questões mais simples (como na maioria das vezes) o `date` e `time` são um baile kk

Comment: @lvcs date tb faz :) `echo date('w');`

Comment: Essa eu não sabia kk

Answer (score 1):

Não iria responder pois estou no celular. Mas resolvi responder.

Pode-se usar a classe `DateTime` (maid recomendável), ou o `time()`:

```
<?php
    $inicio = time(); #pega o tempo atual em segundos (timestamp)
    $fim = $inicio + (15 * 60); #acrescenta 15 minutos ao tempo anterior

    $x = $fim - $inicio; #pega quanto falta em segundos
    $x = $x / 60; # transforma em minutos 

    echo "Faltam {$x} minutos";

    #pode comparar os valores, por exemplo:
    echo ($fim < time()) ? "Foi liberado" : "Ainda nao esta liberado";

     #olho se o numero de segundos do fim é menor que o tempo atual, se sim quer dizer que o tempo em fim ja se tornou passado
```

É claro que o exemplo sempre va falar que faltam 15 minutos, para funcionar normalmente as variáveis inicio e fim devem ser armazenadas em cookies ou sessão.

Deve funcionar, não testei, foi na mente kk

**Editado**

Agora sim, com a pergunta mais ou menos claro, assim resolve:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

    $fim = '16:30:00';
    $inicio = date("H:i:s", time());
    echo "inicio: {$inicio}<br>";
    echo "fim: {$fim}<br>";

    $arrayFim = explode(":", $fim);
    $arrayInicio = explode(":", $inicio);

    $horas = $arrayFim[0] - $arrayInicio[0];
    $minutos = $arrayFim[1] - $arrayInicio[1];
    $segundos = $arrayFim[2] - $arrayInicio[2];
    if($segundos < 0)
    {
        if($minutos > 0)
        {
            $minutos --;
            $segundos = 60 - $arrayInicio[2];
        }
    }
    echo "<br>horas: {$horas}<br>";
    echo "minutos: {$minutos}<br>";
    echo "segundos: {$segundos}<br>";

    if($horas <= 0 and $minutos <= 0 and $segundos <= 0)
        echo "<br>Expirado";
    else
        echo "<br>Nao expirou";
```

Da próxima, cite claramente qual a dúvida :)

Comment: Acho que tem alguma coisa errada ou eu não to sabendo usar.  sempre me retornando  54000 minitos para qualquer horario que coloque

Comment: Acabei me confundindo, é `$x = $x / 60;`

Comment: Outra confusão foi na comparação, não é `>` e sim `<`

Comment: algo ainda não funciona

Comment: coloquei aqui só pra demostração eu sei que no e para PHP https://jsfiddle.net/a5suy5xa/

Comment: Assim não vai funcionar,o tempo é marcado por segundos, estude sobre timestamp. Respondi o que a pergunta estava perguntando, que é sobre comparação de horas, você não deu detalhe suficiente, edite a pergunta ou faça uma nova.

Comment: Mais eu não mudei nada. só coloquei time zone, pra pegar a hora atual da região  e a minha pergunta é o que eu estou precisando, e não coloquei mais detalhes pois aceitava qualquer exemplo que funciona-se

Comment: Editei a resposta com outro código, da próxima seja mais claro na dúvida.

Comment: OK quase isso... e a questão dos 15 minutos? se eu entendi direito voce colocou... se a horario for igual ao atual --> Expirado senão não expirou

Comment: só comparar a variavel minutos, se ela for igual a 15 ou menor vc fala que falta menos que 15 minutos '-'